# Remove a list item from another list item in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I would like to remove a list item from a list. The set up is this: I have a list, lets say it holds persons. Then, when I click on a person in that list, another page opens up, with a new list containing properties of each person. And when I would like to remove a property of a person, I also need to know which person to remove from. The remove of a property is done by a ContextMenu. So, when I long click on a persons property, how do I know which person this is? I need the person, and of course I need the property I want to remove from that person. Is this done by binding, and how? Seems like an easy case, but it really got me thinking, and I can´t come up with a good solution. Thanks!

Comment: you should tell us what DataContexts/ItemsSources the lists have

Comment: I am using MVVM and the DataContext for the two lists are different from each other(e.g. PersonListViewModel and PropertyViewModel), and I think that´s where my problem lies. They have to be different, so it should be a way of going around that. The ItemsSources is of course different as well(e.g. Personlist and Personlist.Properties) where both are simple list structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open the page to edit the properties of the *Person* object, then you should store a reference to it in your ViewModel.

Then when you remove a *Property*, you'll get the *Property* from the ContextMenu, but still have the *Person* reference in your ViewModel.

With both object references, it should be fairly easy.

Comment: That was too easy to think of by my self. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :) I´m a little embarrased by myself right now...